# 415 Unsupported Media Type (JAVA + Angular + RestFULL JSON)

Tags: java, json, angularjs

I hava a problem with my one controller. When i send (POST) data from angular to java controller using ( jason content type ) i see error which is visible in the topic. So I can't catch response from server. Controller catch this request good so in this case book is added to database correctly. Firebug show 404 error but when I checked in Postman I saw **415 Unsupported Media Type**. Why there is such an exception if the controller is working properly.

This is example JSON:

```
{"title":"fgthbfgd","authors":[{"author_id":24,"author":"danielle steel"}],"genres":[{"genre_id":1,"genre":"Dramat"}],"description":"rthg","path_image":"19296.png"}
```

and this is controller:

```
@SuppressWarnings("finally")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/book", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public MessageDTO addNewBook(@RequestBody BookDTO newBook) {
        MessageDTO message = new MessageDTO();
        try {
            bookService.addNewBook(newBook);
            message.setCheck(true);
        } catch (BookTitleException e) {
            message.setCheck(false);
            message.setDescription("Ksiązka o tym tytule juz istnieje.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return message;
        }
    }
```

This is BookDTO

```
public class BookDTO implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5057364006691079475L;

    private Integer id;
    private AuthorEntity [] authors;    
    private String description; 
    private GenreEntity [] genres;  
    private String title;
    private String path_image;
    private double rate;
    private Integer progressBar;
    private boolean flagRate;
    private double userRate;

    /* geters and seters */
}
```

This is Angular code:

```
var bookResource = $resource( $rootScope.restUrl + 'book');

var book = {
            title : $scope.title,
            authors : $scope.author,
            genres : $scope.genre,
            description : $scope.description,
            path_image: null
        }

service.addNewBook = function(book){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        bookResource.save(book)
            .$promise.then( function(data){
                deferred.resolve( data );
            }, function(){
                deferred.reject("Error during adding new book.");
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

This is only a problem in my aplication. In another case all working correctly.

Comment: can u show BookDTO class structure

Comment: Can you add the angularjs call please ?

Comment: I added angular code. But in Postman is the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 415 error because you send your request without the right `content-type` header

```
var bookResource = $resource( $rootScope.restUrl + 'book',{}, {
    save:{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8'} 
    }
});
```

I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: I did a mistake replace `post:`with `save:` I updated my post

Comment: And if you remove the parameter `consumes = "application/json"` of your annotation ?